# How to logout once access_token generated and redirected successfully to redirect_uri in onelogin idp(OIDC)

Tags: api, session, authentication, token, onelogin

I am using onelogin oidc to for login and redirection purpose. It is working fine whenever I am trying to login it logged in me successfully and redirected me to my redirect_uri successfully but I am facing issue How can I logout when I click logout button on my site. Because once I got authorized and redirected to redirect_uri and if again I am trying to authorize then it is redirecting me to redirect_uri but I want a logout functionality also for OIDC

Comment: Which programming language you are using?

Comment: I am using C# language

Comment: There's a number of answers for this. Belt and braces is to use the Onelogin APIs to revoke tokens and logout the users. However, that relies on the client being able to protect the client secret, which some technology stacks can't do. So, my advice for OL clients is usually to ensure you kill kill kill the issued tokens locally. You're then left with dealing with any Onelogin session in the browser that is providing SSO to the IdP.